# Modifying a table

Tags: html, imagesource

Hey I'm having trouble with adding the picture to a HTML Table… planning to use an image from either **Google search** OR pics from my **hard drive.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please share your code to debug easily

Comment: @NagaSaiA <tr>     <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center">Tiffany Paige</td>     <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center">Garlic Naan</td>      <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center"><img src="/http://www.comingsoon.net/assets/uploads/gallery/the-secret-life-of-pets/pts_wild_gidget5_rgb_0325_1.jpg" width="85"></td>   </tr>

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /assets/uploads/gallery/the-secret-life-of-pets/pts_wild_gidget5_rgb_0325_1.jpg" was not found on this server.

Comment: I am getting this error

Comment: I took a pic from the page Google image search

Comment: Created sample valid code with codepen repalce that with the image URL and test

Comment: @NagaSaiA http://www.comingsoon.net/assets/uploads/gallery/the-secret-life-of-pets/pts_wild_gidget5_rgb_0325_1.jpg

Comment: @NagaSaiA that's the link to the picture

Comment: @NagaSaiA IT WORKED! Turns out I had an extra slash in the address link… thanks for taking the time out to help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, please [edit] your post to add any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this info in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax error on your code
1.Closing quotes are misssing for the img src
2.No need to use semi-colon

Same code works fine without syntax error with saome dummy image below

```
<tr>
  <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center">Tiffany Paige</td>
  <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center">Garlic Naan</td>
  <td style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center"><img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" width="85"></td>
</tr>
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/akadRd